# WebDriver / TestNG : Browser launching twice

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Webdriver. I m implementing a datadriven test for my application in firefox browser with Proxy settings. Somehow my browser is  launched twice while executing. Can someone please help me on what went wrong

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.ProxyType;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

import jxl.*;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class Datadriven_login {

    public static WebDriver ff =  new FirefoxDriver();


  @Test
  public void f() throws BiffException, IOException, Throwable {

      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream ("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Datadriven.xls");
      Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
      Sheet s = w.getSheet(0);
      for(int rows =1 ; rows <= s.getRows(); rows++)

      {
          FirefoxProfile ffp = new FirefoxProfile();
          ffp.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());
          ff = new FirefoxDriver(ffp);
          ff.get("https://xyz.do");

          String username = s.getCell(0, rows).getContents();

          ff.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TableMain']/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(username);
          String password = s.getCell(1, rows).getContents();
          System.out.println( rows + "-" +  "-" + username + "/"+ password);
          ff.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TableMain']/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(password);
```

Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you instantiate a new `WebDriver`, a new browser will open.

Hence, this line:

`public static WebDriver ff =  new FirefoxDriver();`

and this line:

`ff = new FirefoxDriver(ffp)`

both instantiate it.  I would recommend changing the first line to:

`public static WebDriver ff;`

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated FirfoxDriver twice.

Replace

> public static WebDriver ff =  new FirefoxDriver();

with

> public static WebDriver ff;